# Macbook suddenly refusing password

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, password, filevault

Mid-work at airport, Macbook pops login screen. All of a sudden stops accepting my password (which is same password used for all services).

After researching the issue and talking to Apple I was presented with the following options:

1. Reset with Apple ID. When I try this, I get "Unknown error occurred"
2. All options in Recovery OS
3. Unlock Volume HD

I never set up FileVault though. So currently Macbook is bricked, I'm in a country without a Genius Bar, and all my work is on the machine...

Anybody else experiencing these issues? Anything worked?

Answer (score 2):

I haven’t come across this, but it may be worth trying to create an additional Admin account and logging into that to reset your password on your current account.

**How to create an additional Admin account**

You can do this by tricking your Mac into thinking it's being set up as new:

1. Boot into Single User Mode by restarting your Mac and pressing and holding <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> as soon as you hear the startup chime
2. Keep these keys down until you see a black screen with white text
3. Mount your drive by typing in `/sbin/mount -uw /` and then pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key
4. Remove the Apple Setup Done file by typing in 
   `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and then pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key
5. Now reboot your Mac by typing in `reboot` and then pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key
6. Follow the prompts to complete the setup process and create a **new** admin account

Once you've done the above, try starting up and logging in as the new admin user. Assuming you can, then see if you can edit the password in your old account (just try *changing* it to your existing password).

---

**[UPDATE]**

Since we've established that even trying to boot into Single User Mode isn't working for you and that trying to do so results in the normal login screen appearing, I think we'd better investigate the possibility that your keyboard is faulty. This would explain your password not being accepted and the fact that pressing keys during startup may not have the desired result.

The best way to test this is to connect a USB keyboard and try using that. If you haven't got one, any cheap USB keyboard will do.

Comment: Actually not able to launch Single User Mode. Terminal flahses for a second and then pops up the login screen. Maybe open separate issue?

Comment: Hmm, is it a grey screen with an Apple logo at top, your user account below it (a bit like a login screen) and a password field below that?

Comment: Nono, the regular one, with blur background etc

Comment: Hmm, I've just had a thought. What model MacBook Pro have you got?

Comment: I got MacBookPro14,1

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Let me know how you go.